# Ubuntu Trusty ros-indigo-adhoc-communication package

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The ros-indigo-adhoc-communication Ubuntu package seems to be incomplete.  For example, it doesn't seem to install the adhoc-communication node.

Using adhoc_communication after installing this results in this error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [adhoc_communication/adhoc_communication]: can't locate node [adhoc_communication] in package [adhoc_communication]
```

Note that it also does not include a launch directory - I had to copy it over from the git repo.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

The following files are installed with this package:

**dpkg-query -L ros-indigo-adhoc-communication**

```
/.
/opt
/opt/ros
/opt/ros/indigo
/opt/ros/indigo/include
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendQuaternionResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpClusterElement.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpFrontier.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmControlRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpCluster.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendOccupancyGridResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ShutDown.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpAuction.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/MmListOfPoints.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpClusterRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ShutDownResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ChangeMCMembership.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmPointRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ChangeMCMembershipRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetGroupState.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmControlResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ShutDownRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmRobotPosition.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/CMgrRobotUpdate.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpAuction.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendCMgrRobotUpdate.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetNeighborsResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendStringResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendTwistRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetNeighbors.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmPointResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpCluster.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendOccupancyGridRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdateRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendTwist.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpAuctionElement.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendOccupancyGrid.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/MmRobotPosition.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastStringResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmRobotPositionRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendCMgrRobotUpdateRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmMapUpdateRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpClusterResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmPoint.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpAuctionRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/MmMapUpdate.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetNeighborsRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/RecvString.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendQuaternion.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendTwistResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdateResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ChangeMCMembershipResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmMapUpdate.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpFrontier.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/MmControl.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/ExpFrontierElement.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendQuaternionRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetGroupStateRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmMapUpdateResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmRobotPositionResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendMmControl.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpAuctionResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendString.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpFrontierRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastString.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendExpFrontierResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/MmPoint.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/GetGroupStateResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendStringRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/SendCMgrRobotUpdateResponse.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/BroadcastStringRequest.h
/opt/ros/indigo/include/adhoc_communication/CMgrDimensions.h
/opt/ros/indigo/lib
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig/adhoc_communication.pc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpAuction.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendTwist.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmMapUpdate.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendCMgrRobotUpdate.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_ChangeMCMembership.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_ChangeMCMembership.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmPoint.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendString.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_BroadcastString.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpCluster.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmControl.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmRobotPosition.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmMapUpdate.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_GetNeighbors.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_GetNeighbors.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmPoint.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_ShutDown.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendOccupancyGrid.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendOccupancyGrid.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_GetGroupState.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/__init__.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmRobotPosition.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/__init__.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_BroadcastString.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendQuaternion.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpCluster.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendString.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpFrontier.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpFrontier.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_GetGroupState.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendMmControl.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_ShutDown.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendExpAuction.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendTwist.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendQuaternion.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/srv/_SendCMgrRobotUpdate.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpFrontierElement.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_RecvString.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmRobotPosition.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpCluster.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmListOfPoints.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmRobotPosition.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmListOfPoints.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpFrontier.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpFrontierElement.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_CMgrDimensions.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmPoint.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpAuctionElement.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpClusterElement.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmMapUpdate.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpAuction.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmControl.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpFrontier.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpAuction.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmPoint.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_CMgrRobotUpdate.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/__init__.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_CMgrRobotUpdate.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/__init__.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_RecvString.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_CMgrDimensions.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmMapUpdate.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpCluster.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_MmControl.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpAuctionElement.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/msg/_ExpClusterElement.py
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/__init__.pyc
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adhoc_communication/__init__.py
/opt/ros/indigo/share
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/cmake
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/cmake/adhoc_communicationConfig.cmake
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/cmake/adhoc_communication-msg-extras.cmake
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/cmake/adhoc_communication-msg-paths.cmake
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/cmake/adhoc_communicationConfig-version.cmake
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendOccupancyGrid.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpCluster.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendString.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmPoint.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/ChangeMCMembership.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/GetNeighbors.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/ShutDown.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendQuaternion.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmMapUpdate.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmRobotPosition.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/GetGroupState.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmControl.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpFrontier.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/BroadcastString.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendTwist.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpAuction.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/srv/SendCMgrRobotUpdate.srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/package.xml
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/MmRobotPosition.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/CMgrDimensions.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/MmPoint.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/MmControl.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpAuctionElement.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpFrontierElement.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/MmMapUpdate.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/MmListOfPoints.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpAuction.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpCluster.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpClusterElement.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/RecvString.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/CMgrRobotUpdate.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpFrontier.msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendExpFrontier.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_ShutDown.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/ChangeMCMembership.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendCMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/GetGroupState.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_BroadcastString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_GetNeighbors.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendTwist.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/adhoc_communication-srv.asd
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmMapUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_GetGroupState.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendOccupancyGrid.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendOccupancyGrid.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendExpCluster.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendQuaternion.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendTwist.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmRobotPosition.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/BroadcastString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmControl.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpAuction.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendExpAuction.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpCluster.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendCMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendMmMapUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendMmRobotPosition.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/GetNeighbors.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendMmControl.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/ShutDown.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendQuaternion.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_BroadcastCMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_ChangeMCMembership.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendExpFrontier.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/_package_SendMmPoint.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/srv/SendMmPoint.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpClusterElement.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpAuction.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_RecvString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_MmControl.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_MmListOfPoints.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/RecvString.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpFrontierElement.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpAuctionElement.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/MmPoint.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpFrontier.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_MmRobotPosition.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/adhoc_communication-msg.asd
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpAuction.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/MmListOfPoints.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpFrontierElement.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpAuctionElement.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_MmPoint.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/MmMapUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpCluster.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_CMgrDimensions.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/MmControl.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpFrontier.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_CMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_MmMapUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/_package_ExpCluster.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/CMgrDimensions.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/CMgrRobotUpdate.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/MmRobotPosition.lisp
/opt/ros/indigo/share/common-lisp/ros/adhoc_communication/msg/ExpClusterElement.lisp
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ros-indigo-adhoc-communication
/usr/share/doc/ros-indigo-adhoc-communication/changelog.Debian.gz
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221839/ubuntu-trusty-ros-indigo-adhoc-communication-package/) by [thekamz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25225/thekamz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The ros-indigo-adhoc-communication Ubuntu package seems to be incomplete.

Looking at the *install section* of the `CMakeLists.txt` of `adhoc_communication` ([here](https://github.com/aau-ros/aau_multi_robot/blob/404699fd68b51aeca1a1d9865684b130c10fab07/adhoc_communication/CMakeLists.txt#L175-L208)), I'd say you're right. All the relevant `install(..)` statements are either commented, or just part of the boilerplate comments.

I guess the package is/was mostly used built from-sources (and by sourcing the `devel/` space).

> Any ideas on how to fix this?

You can't directly fix this. You could consider fixing the `CMakeLists.txt` and submitting a pull-request against [aau-ros/aau_multi_robot](https://github.com/aau-ros/aau_multi_robot). The package maintainer(s) will then have to do a re-release.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thekamz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25225/thekamz/) on 2015-12-01**:
I'll work on the cmake issue.  In the mean time, I did a catkin build from [aau-ros/aau_multi_robot](https://github.com/aau-ros/aau_multi_robot) and [was unsuccessful for a different reason](http://answers.ros.org/question/221856/adhoc_communication-errors-with-indigo-on-ubuntu-trusty/).